# how to use"and" in a list

Tags: lists

> Glucose lowering agents consist of multiple subcategories of drugs, including metformin, DPP-4 inhibitors, and insulin and analogues.

My question is how should I write a list with an "and" in one of the items? in this example: is "and 'insulin and analogues'" right?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the sentence as you have presented it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use two "and"s in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100299/can-you-use-two-ands-in-a-sentence) ( "I like chocolate, vanilla, and lemon and orange ice cream.") ( "I like chocolate, vanilla, and lemon & orange ice cream." was one suggestion.) Here, there is little need for clarification, though ' ... and insulin and its analogues' might make the reading even clearer.